# "Access denied" when trying to update an alert for a user

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

i am getting this error when trying to update an alert for a user in the team discussion list. 
My code is :

```
    SPUser user = mysite.OpenWeb().CurrentUser;

    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        SPSite site = new SPSite(mysite.ID);
        SPWeb myweb = site.OpenWeb();

        string id = this.Page.Request.QueryString["RootFolder"].ToString();
        string[] rootfolder = id.Split(@"//".ToCharArray());
        myweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPList mylsit = myweb.Lists["Team Discussion"];


        SPListItem item = mylsit.GetItemById(21);


        SPUser curruser = myweb.EnsureUser(user.LoginName);
        Response.Write(curruser.LoginName);

        SPAlert newAlert = user.Alerts.Add();
        newAlert.AlertType = SPAlertType.Item;

        newAlert.Item = item;

        newAlert.Properties["eventtypeindex"] = "1";

        newAlert.AlertFrequency = SPAlertFrequency.Immediate;

        newAlert.Update(false);

        myweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    });
```

And i am getting the error when the alert.update() is executing. please help me on this

Comment: i fixed this error but email alerts are not working. The code is working fine. I verified this by checking in Site Settigs -> User alerts. The only problem is that emails are not sent to the user. In the above code, is there any element missing?

Comment: I am also having same issue facing. It is trowing access denied error. But alerts are setting up and welcome email are not sent to user. application pool identity user is farm admin, site collection admin. Still the same error. How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see of note is the "! Important" section in the below MSDN article on the RunWithElevatedPrivileges function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx

It would seem you are doing some form of writing, and may not have called ValidateFormDigest?

Comment: now its working fine but the problem is that, when any user prompted for alerts, alerts is activated but no emails are sent to the user. what to do?

Comment: @Abhimanyu: I'm afraid I can't help with that further issue, it may well need a separate question to get the attention of someone with more alert debugging experience.

Comment: @Abhimanyu - do you get any alerts at all? If not go through the troubleshooting here http://sharepointalert.info/troubleshooting-sharepoint-alerts/

Comment: @Ryan - i am not getting any alerts. But when alerts are activated to the users who requested it. I verified this by checking in Site Settigs -> User alerts. The only problem is that emails are not sent to the user. In the above code, is there any element missing?